# stream/post facebook updates to a wordpress site?

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Is there a plugin or relatively simple way to have updates made on a facebook group page show up live (or near live) on a wordpress site?

Thanks!

Comment: May be a better fit on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post. It's a matter of searching through plugins for what you're looking for. Also keep in the mind the group would have to be public. http://wpapi.com/10-great-wordpress-plugins-for-facebook/